# ID selector not recognised

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know there are dozens of similar questions and some of them have helped me get to this point but I can't see any rhyme or reason to this error.

I've tagged an image with the id `HeaderGradient` and I'm trying to set it's size in the css file but it's not working. When I inspect the element in Firefox there is no mention of my css file. I'm using the Bootstrap framework. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {     
  #HeaderGradient {
    width: 80%;
    height: 141px; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" id="Logo" alt="EP Logo">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="images/header_gradient.png" id="HeaderGradient" alt="Gradient Image">
      </div> 
    </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's not a valid css syntax

Comment: If you want to write your CSS like that, then your going to need to use a precompiler like SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid CSS code for this, It should be

```
#HeaderGradient {
   width: 80%;
   height: 141px; 
}
```

```css
#HeaderGradient {
  width: 80%;
  height: 141px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png" id="Logo" alt="EP Logo">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="images/header_gradient.png" id="HeaderGradient" alt="Gradient Image">
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not a valid CSS syntax update the syntax as follows to get `#HeaderGradient` within `body` tag.

```
body #HeaderGradient{
   width: 80%;
   height: 141px; 
}
```

Comment: Of course the body tag is pretty redundant anyway as all content will be in there regardless.

Comment: @DavidG : yes it's but it may help to understand the syntax

Answer (score 1):

You have the ID selector in the wrong place. Instead of:

```
body {

    #HeaderGradient{
      ....
    }
}
```

Move the selector outside:

```
body {
    ....
}
#HeaderGradient{
  ....
}
```

If you want to use that kind of CSS syntax you need to use a CSS preprocessor. Check out [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)